# How filter out JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object

I need to filter a huge JSON file based on its value.

this is my JSON code(this is part of my JSON object, In real behaviour, its have more than 1000).

```
var jsonObject = [  
   {  
      "UserId":10259,
      "FullName":"hello world",
      "CustomerId":"10165"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10405,
      "FullName":"test value",
      "CustomerId":"10261"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10400,
      "FullName":"mark ant",
      "CustomerId":"10161"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":16224,
      "FullName":"jhon cena",
      "CustomerId":""
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10416,
      "FullName":"shoze ahh",
      "CustomerId":"1"
   },
   {  
      "UserId":10244,
      "FullName":"kajal man",
      "CustomerId":"10"
   }
];
```

To filter the above JSON object, I used the following filter function.

```
function usersBasedOnIDs(CustomerIds) {
    if (CustomerIds == "") {
        console.log(jsonObject);
    } else if (CustomerIds == "9999xx") {

        let result = jsonObject.filter(c => c.CustomerId == "");
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        let result = jsonObject.filter(c => c.CustomerId != "" && CustomerIds.includes(c.CustomerId));
        console.log(result);
    }   
}
```

How I call the function

```
usersBasedOnIDs("");
usersBasedOnIDs("10261,10165");
usersBasedOnIDs("9999xx");
```

There are a couple of problems with my code,

1. This function not working with IE 11 an early version
2. And another thing is when I call the function as `usersBasedOnIDs("10261,10165");` or `usersBasedOnIDs("10261");` , its returns   follwing JSON output

   `{UserId: 10405, FullName: "test value", CustomerId: "10261"}
   {UserId: 10416, FullName: "shoze ahh", CustomerId: "1"}
   {UserId: 10244, FullName: "kajal man", CustomerId: "10"}`

But my expectation is, only this

```
{UserId: 10405, FullName: "test value", CustomerId: "10261"}
```

How can change the function to avoid **those two problems**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the full answer for IE 11, based on @adiga answer. Change the arrow function to normal function and using [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) instead of `includes`.

```js
const array = [
  { UserId: 10259, FullName: "hello world", CustomerId: "10165" },
  { UserId: 10405, FullName: "test value", CustomerId: "10261" },
  { UserId: 10400, FullName: "mark ant", CustomerId: "10161" },
  { UserId: 16224, FullName: "jhon cena", CustomerId: "" },
  { UserId: 10416, FullName: "shoze ahh", CustomerId: "1" },
  { UserId: 10244, FullName: "kajal man", CustomerId: "10" }
];

function usersBasedOnIDs(CustomerIds) {
  if (CustomerIds === "") return array;

  if (CustomerIds == "9999xx") {
    return array.filter(function(c) {
      return c.CustomerId == "";
    });
  }

  const ids = CustomerIds.split(",");
  return array.filter(function(c) {
    return c.CustomerId !== "" && ids.indexOf(c.CustomerId) > -1;
  });
}

console.log(usersBasedOnIDs("10261,10165"))
```

Comment: This is a better option considering this works without a polyfill.

Comment: @adiga Thank for your answer and humble qualities. problem solve. Thanks for both of you :)

Comment: @Sachith please [mark this answer as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) if your issue is resolved

Answer (score 3):

The string `"10261,10165"` includes `10261` as well as the strings `1` and `10`. This is why you are getting those ids filtered as well.

Instead, you can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string at `,` first to get an array of customer Ids and then use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const array=[{"UserId":10259,"FullName":"hello world","CustomerId":"10165"},{"UserId":10405,"FullName":"test value","CustomerId":"10261"},{"UserId":10400,"FullName":"mark ant","CustomerId":"10161"},{"UserId":16224,"FullName":"jhon cena","CustomerId":""},{"UserId":10416,"FullName":"shoze ahh","CustomerId":"1"},{"UserId":10244,"FullName":"kajal man","CustomerId":"10"}]

function usersBasedOnIDs(CustomerIds) {
    if (CustomerIds === "")
        return array;
    
    if (CustomerIds == "9999xx")
      return array.filter(c => c.CustomerId == "")
    
   const ids =  CustomerIds.split(",");
   return array.filter(c => c.CustomerId !== "" && ids.includes(c.CustomerId));
}

console.log(usersBasedOnIDs("10261,10165"))
console.log(usersBasedOnIDs("10261"))
```

IE11 doesn't support arrow functions, `String#includes` and `Array#includes`. You can change your arrow function to:

```
array.filter(function(c) {
  return c.CustomerId == ""
})
```

And

Use a polyfill for [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill) and [`String#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill)

Comment: Thank you, but please read my question, there is another problem. this `includes` and lambda expressions not working IE 11 and its early versions

Comment: @Sachith you can change arrow function to normal function and use indexOf instead of includes to resolve the problem

Comment: Yeah I tried with `indexOf` but its not working, sometimes it could be my fault, can u please give me a final answer to sort this out

Comment: @Sachith there are plenty of duplicates for that. You need to replace arrow functiosn with regular function. You also need to use polyfills for `String#includes `and `Array#includes`

Comment: @adiga I'm not clear it, can you update your answer to sort out IE problem, please...

Comment: @Sachith I have already added at the bottom of the answer. You need to add the polyfill from the link mentioned

Comment: @Sachith you copy the code mentioned in the link and include it in one of your javascript file before you use `includes`. Basically, you are adding `Array.prototype.includes` so that your array can access it

Comment: @Sachith also vicnoob has added an answer using indexOf which doesn't invlove adding a polyfill

Answer (score 1):

1 ) IE 11 not support arrow functions

try changing your function to

```
var result = jsonObject.filter(function(c) { return c.CustomerId === ""; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason your code does not work on IE 11 is that it uses the includes function for checking if array contains a value. The [includes function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) is supported in IE 14 and above. Also [arrow functions](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp) are not supported in IE 11 and earlier.

Your code wont work because of a couple of bugs. Firstly the arrow function callback needs a return statement. So instead of:

```
c => c.CustomerId == ""
```

use:

c => return (c.CustomerId == "")

Also the customer ids should be passed as an array instead of a string. So instead of using:

```
usersBasedOnIDs("10261,10165");
```

You need to use:

```
usersBasedOnIDs([10261,10165]);
```